# TypeError when using datetime objects for plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot the graph as I want time in x axis and integer data in y axis. 
I am getting the following error

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

`plt.plot(time,data)`
on the above command it is showing the error
time contains the data points from after every one minute of interval 15:46:00 to 16:45:00
i have also checked the data type also it is showing datetime for time .

```
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib
import datetime as db
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


time=["16:45:00","16:46:00","16:47:00","16:48:00","16:49:00","16:50:00"]
data=[1,2,1,3,4,6]
time1=[]
for tr in time:  
  t=db.datetime.strptime(tr,"%H:%M:%S").time()
  time1.append(t)
plt.plot(time1,data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: there is nothing much in code one array is there containing the time and other is containing the data point in it .

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1725, in _upda
    path = line.get_path()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 938, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 625, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `.time()` from your `datetime.strptime`

```
time = ["16:45:00", "16:46:00", "16:47:00", "16:48:00", "16:49:00", "16:50:00"]
data = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6]
time1 = []
for tr in time:
    t = db.datetime.strptime(tr, "%H:%M:%S")
    time1.append(t)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time1, data)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()  formats the x-axis to get rotate the tick labels 
plt.show()
```

This produces the figure:

[image]

However, this gives you some extra zeros at the end of the datetimes. In order to remove this then the datetimes need to be formatted. This can be done by using matplotlibs [DateFormatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter).

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

time = ["16:45:00", "16:46:00", "16:47:00", "16:48:00", "16:49:00", "16:50:00"]
data = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6]
time1 = []
for tr in time:
    t = db.datetime.strptime(tr, "%H:%M:%S")
    time1.append(t)

#format the plotting of the datetime to avoid times like 12:45:00.00000000
date_formatter = DateFormatter('%H.%M.%S')

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time1, data)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

This produces a nice looking figure:

[image]

Comment: Thnx a lot it worked for me after removing the .time()

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark as accepted by pressing the tick button next to the answer

Comment: These will be better by default in 2.0 http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/dflt_style_changes.html#autodateformatter-format-strings